# JavaScript continiously changing colour of SVG element - flickers

Tags: javascript, css

I have an element and I'm changing its colour with timer:

```
r = 0.05;
delta = 0.05;
function changecol(){
  if (r < 0.05 || r > 0.95) delta = delta * (-1);
  r += delta;
  col = '#'+(Math.floor(r*255)).toString(16)+(Math.floor(r*255)).toString(16)+(Math.floor(r*255)).toString(16);
  svg_elem.style.fill = col;
  setTimeout("changecol()", 50);
}
```

So colour changes from white to black and back, `r*255` keeps it between 00 and FF, everything goes smoothly but when it goes to Black, it flickers to White and starts ascending up basically. Have I missed some error in calculations?

here's a jFiddle with a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/b4f58bz2/

Comment: @JK. I'm not sure what you're on about to be honest

Comment: col = "hsl(0,0%," + (r * 100) + "%)";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change from black to white you can simply use the Lightness part of HSL with 0% saturation, giving that as color argument:

Replacing `setTimeout()` with `requestAnimationFrame()` will also make the animation much smoother as this will sync to the monitor vblank updates. Just compensate by reducing delta to about half.

#### Example using a div

```js
var l = 5;
var delta = 2.5;

(function changecol() {
  if (l < 5 || l > 95) delta = -delta;
  l += delta;
  d.style.backgroundColor = "hsl(0,0%," + l + "%)";
  requestAnimationFrame(changecol);
})();
```

```html
<div id=d>Ping-pong fade</div>
```

Comment: I like this solution, although I couldn't get the animation to trigger, so I ended up leaving the timeout for now. I just put this code in the `<script>` and colour don't change

Comment: @Amir remember I just put in som dummy id's in this demo as I don't have access to the original svg. Just replace d. with the id of the svg (or obtain it using getElementById). The script must also run *after* the DOM has loaded. If the script is in header wrap the code inside a window.onload = function() { ... code here ...}, or move the script to the bottom of the document before the body close tag. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I ran a console.debug on your jsfiddle and I found that the result of `(Math.floor(r*255)).toString(16)` when it flickers is 'C' in hex, just before '0'. The problem is that when translated to css color it's: `#ccc` which equals to `#cccccc` which is a very light color instead of a dark one. You have to pad the result of `(Math.floor(r*255)).toString(16)` with a leading 0 if its length is less than 2, like:

```
color = (Math.floor(r*255)).toString(16);
if (color.length < 2) {
  color = "0" + color;
}
```

then just make:

```
col = '#' + color + color + color;
```

I hope this gets you on the right track.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to say. Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/b4f58bz2/1/

Answer (score 1):

This took a bit.

The problem is your conversion of toString(16), you aren't considering the possibility that your hex code is too short.

```
 R = hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
```

Please see:

```js
r = 0.05;
delta = 0.05;

function changecol() {
  if (r < 0.05 || r > 0.95) delta = delta * (-1);
  r += delta;
  hex = (Math.floor(r * 255)).toString(16);
  R = hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
  col = '#' + R + R + R;

  document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundColor = col;

  setTimeout("changecol()", 300);
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', changecol, false);
```

```html
<div id="test">
  ADFASDF
</div>
<div id="test1">
  ADFASDF
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry Kirito, didn't see your answer before I posted mine

Comment: That's why I always reload before posting. I was about to answer in the same time as you both did.

Comment: It's all good. The more answers the better for the development community :)

Answer (score 1):

The other poster already mentioned your bug in encoding small values, so that `#0C0C0C` for example is encoded as `#CCC` wich actually represents `#CCCCCC`.

Besides that your code has some more bad practices in it.

First: use local variables! some may be "needed" global, but `col` for example has no reason at all, to be made global. That's just environmental pollution.

Next: pass the function to setTimeout, not a string that has to be parsed.

```
setTimeout(changecol, 50);
```

It's faster, it's cleaner, it can be encapsulated, it can be minified, ... only benefits.

Then, with a little trick, you can rewrite your color-encoding to be way nicer:

```
var c = 255 * r;
var col = "#" + (0x1000000 | c << 16 | c << 8 | c).toString(16).substr(1);
```

the 0x1000000 is padding, so that the values always exceed 6 digits, followed by the three color channels (r, g, b).

This value is converted to a hex-value, having a 1 in front of it from the padding, wich then is removed by the substr(1). Therefore we have always exactly 6 hexadecimal digits, 2 per color-channel, no worrying about leading zeroes and stuff.

And the bit-operations also strip all decimal-places that `c` might have.

And don't use body-onload to start this thing. If you really have to, use jQuery ($(changecol)) or search for a DOMContentLoaded-implementation, ... or just put the script at the end of the body and know therefore that is executed after all the html is parsed, and the dom is built.

---

But imo. we can do even better than that. We can make this thing a function of time, instead of incrementing and decrementing the value, and giving it a padding of 5% so you don't go over the borders, ...

```
var startTime = Date.now();
var speed = 255 / 1000;   //255 shades of gray / 1000ms

//this means every 2 seconds this animation completes 
//a full cycle from black to white to black again.
//or you slow the speed down to `2*255 / 30000` for example
//1cycle per 30seconds

function changecol(){
    //first we calculate the passed time since the start (in ms) 
    //and then we multiply it by the speed by wich the value should change
    //the amount of color-steps per ms
    var t = (Date.now() - startTime) * speed;

    //now we get the fraction of 256 wich defines the shade
    /*
        var c = Math.floor(t % 256);
    */
    //since we're dealing with powers of 2 we can use a bit-mask to extract just 
    //the last 8 bit of the value and do basically the same, including the Math.floor()
    var c = t & 0xFF;

    //every other interval we have to change the direction, so that we fade back from white to black
    //and don't start over from 0 to 255 (black to white)
    /*
        var interval = Math.floor(t / 256);  //get the interval
        if(interval % 2 === 1)               //check wether it's odd
            c = 255 - c;  //revert the direction
    */
    //but again we can do easyer by simply checking the 9th bit. 
    //if it's a 1, this is an odd interval. the 9th bit equals 0x100 (256).
    if(t & 0x100) //mask only the 9th bit. returns either 256 (wich is true) or 0 (false)
        c = 0xFF - c;  //revert the direction

    var col = "#" + (0x1000000 | c << 16 | c << 8 | c).toString(16).substr(1);
    test.style.color = col;

    //using animation-frames to stay in sync with the rest of animation in the browser.
    requestAnimationFrame(changecol);
}
changecol();  //start this thing, don't use body-onload
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this instead, that way you don't have to try and figure out the correct HEX code.

```js
var whatColor = true;
fadeColor = function() {

  var color = whatColor ? 'white' : 'black';
  $('svg circle').css({fill: color});
  whatColor = !whatColor;
  setTimeout(function() {
    fadeColor();
  }, 1000);
  
}
fadeColor();
```

```css
svg circle {
  -webkit-transition: fill 1s;
  transition: fill 1s;
  fill: black;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg class="mySVG" height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"  />
</svg>
```

Comment: Nice use of transitions on an SVG object.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I figured out why his code wasn't working but figured this saved time over solving that equation.